# Set the Resource String in javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, .net-3.5, resources

How can I set the resource string in javascript?

I have a resource file called, for example,

```
myResourceFile.resx
```

in my code and using the literal control I can use:

```
lblName.Text = Resources.myResourceFile.ajaxRetrievingInformation;

<asp:Literal id="lit" runat="server" 
             Text="<%$ Resources:myResourceFile, ajaxRetrievingInformation%>" />
```

but if I try this in javascript, like:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnImportCompaniesAndEmployees" 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="myButtonCssClass"
            OnClick="btnImportCompaniesAndEmployees_Click"
            OnClientClick="strLoadingText='<%$ Resources:myResourceFile, ajaxRetrievingInformation%>';return true;"
            ...
/>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var strLoadingText = '<%$ Resources:myResourceFile, ajaxRetrievingInformation%>';
</script>
```

I get errors...

Does anyone know how to manage this? 
**Something like**:

```
var strLoadingText = Resources.GetString(myResourceFile, ajaxRetrievingInformation);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var strLoadingText = "<%= Resources.myResourceFile.ajaxRetrievingInformation %>";
</script>
```

Comment: how easy can that be! :) Thanks

Comment: MVC 3: `var errorBlank = '<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, General_Error%>" />';`

Comment: what happens if the string has as pecial character say ' apostophe

Comment: @AlanFord, an apostrophe won't hurt anything, but switch to `<%:` if you want it safely encoded. I use `<%:` exclusively these days.